# Checking Whether user input 3x3 multidimensional array is a Markov Matrix

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a java program that prints whether a user input 3x3 multidimensional array is a Markov matrix; the prompt is below.

-An n x n matrix is called a positive Markov matrix if each
-element is positive and the sum of the elements in each column is 1. Write the -following method to check whether a matrix is a Markov matrix.

`public static boolean isMarkovMatrix(double [][] m)`

-Write a test program (the main method) that prompts the user to enter a 3 x 3 --matrix of double
-values and tests whether it is a Markov matrix.

My output for the code prints out that it is not a Markov matrix no matter what I input, and can't figure out why it's doing that. As a side note, I don't know any complex java, and have only been in class for a few weeks so what is below is the extent of my java programming skills. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declarations 
        double[][] markov = new double[3][3];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //input 
        System.out.print("Please enter numbers to fill up a 3x3 matrix: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < markov.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < markov.length; x++) {
                markov[i][x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        //output
        if (isMarkov(markov) == true) {
            System.out.print("Your matrix is a Markov Matrix!");
        } else if (isMarkov(markov) == false) {
            System.out.print("Your matrix is not a Markov Matrix!");
        }

        //close keyboard
        keyboard.close();

    }

    //method to check whether the matrix is positive
    public static boolean isPositive(double[][] array) {
        //declarations 
        boolean answer = true;

        //processing
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                if (array[i][x] < 0) {
                    answer = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    //method to check whether the sum of the columns are 1
    public static boolean columnSum(double[][] array) {
        //declarations 
        double sum = 0;
        boolean answer = true;

        //processing
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                sum += array[i][x];
            }
            if (sum != 1) {
                answer = false;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    //method to check whether the matrix is a Markov matrix
    public static boolean isMarkov(double[][] array) {
        //declarations
        boolean answer = false;

        //processing 
        if ((isPositive(array) == true) && (columnSum(array) == true)) {
            answer = true;
        }
        return answer;

    }

}
```

Comment: In your columSum method, the pb is sum !=1 . you dont compare double like that due to floating point. Use Java.lang.Double.compare().https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_compare.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in *columnSum(double[][] array)* function. The *sum* value is not reset after every column. That means your code sums up all columns in the value *sum*. Simply resetting *sum* to zero in the outer for loop should prevent this. If there is another problem, please let me know, I'll look over it again.

```
//method to check whether the sum of the columns are 1
public static boolean columnSum (double[][] array)
{
    //declarations 
    double sum = 0; 
    boolean answer = true;

    //processing
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        sum = 0; //-----------------added-----------------
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
        {
            sum += array[i][x]; 
        }
        if (sum != 1)
        {
            answer = false; 
        }
    }
    return answer;  
}
```

On another note, just a small nice thing since you are somewhat new to coding. when evaluating boolean values, you don't need to add the *==true* or *==false*. The value itself is boolean. Example given here:

```
//instead of
if (flag == false){}
//do
if (!flag){}
```

In case you do not know, the "!" negates the expression. If you want to evaluate "true", just remove the "!".

Comment: Thanks for that info, didn't know that! But I've reset the sum to 0 and it's still saying that everything isn't a Markov matrix :(

Comment: Ok I just tested it myself and for (0.3 0.3 0.4) in all 3 lines and it works correctly and says that it is indeed a markov matrix. Could you please give me a test case where it should work, but doesn't.

Comment: oh never mind it does work I accidentally entered a wrong digit haha Thanks for your help appreciated it :)